# Send List<Object> as a return in a SOAP service method

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to send a list of objects as a response in a SOAP call and I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'SoapCore.Extensibility.IFaultExceptionTransformer' has been registered.
```

Also, I tried with a list of strings and the request works fine.

```
namespace Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class MyCustomModel
    {
       [DataMember]
       public int Id { get; set; }
       [DataMember]
       public string Name { get; set; }
       [DataMember]
       public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Models
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IServiceExample
    {
        [OperationContract]
        PatientActivity TestPatientActivity(PatientActivity patientActivity);
        [OperationContract]
        List<MyCustomModel> getAll();
    }
}
```

And in service's implementation I am just returning a list of objects.

I followed this tutorial: https://dottutorials.net/creating-soap-web-services-dot-net-core-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

Solved this issue by creating an empty constructor for the entity and by adding in ConfigureServices -> services.AddMvc() & services.AddSoapCore().

Answer (score 0):

Whilst upgrading our webservice (netcoreapp 2.2 to 3.1) I ran into this Exception.

Editing **Startup.cs** to add

```
services.AddSoapCore();
```

to **ConfigureServices** resolved this issue for me.